# Android Studio Emulator MacOS Sonoma Camera issues

Tags: android-studio

I'm having issues connecting my macbook camera on the android studio emulator. Ever since I've updated to MacOS Sonoma im not able to use the camera on the emulators anymore.

I've checked on terminal what the issue might be and I got back this warning:

WARNING: AVCaptureDeviceTypeExternal is deprecated for Continuity Cameras. Please use AVCaptureDeviceTypeContinuityCamera and add NSCameraUseContinuityCameraDeviceType to your Info.plist.

It seems that the camera descriptions on sonoma has changed could anyone help to see how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Edit]
After further investigation, I have a found the answer.
Get this, it's a feature lol.

Hope this helps anyone with the issue as well.

**https://support.apple.com/en-us/108387**

[Original]
I can confirm this is a massive issue, and one that is going to be a pain for many MacOS App Devs.

Your conclusion that Apple changed the descriptor for Camera selection in MacOS Sonoma is accurate (I assume this is in part by the massive addition to use your phone as a camera natively within MacOS. However Apple still should not have). This has left a massive useless sticker on many major applications including Android Studio. Please reach out to the application devs for each instance this problem occurs, in this case I would start with the Android Dev team on all possible platforms. This needs to become a more known within the MacOS developer community so the proper checks can be implemented and problems for major vendors are mitigated, especially as Sonoma users continue to grow.

This is major stuff, basic camera features...

If anyone has any updates or workarounds, I would love to know!